# Installing an application based from the installer path using process.start

Tags: vb.net, process.start

Hi how can I install an application for example it was stored in C:\Temp\Filename\Filename\abc.exe and using process.start. Here's my code

```
    Dim wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim wp = New WindowsPrincipal(wi)
    Dim path = "C:\Temp\Unzip\IDGo800_Minidriver_32.zip\IDGo800_Minidriver_32"
    Dim runAsAdmin As Boolean = wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)

    If Not runAsAdmin Then

        ' The following properties run the new process as administrator
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
        startInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
        startInfo.Arguments = "msiexec /i " & path & "\IDGo800_Minidriver_64.msi"" ALLUSERS=1 /qn /norestart"""
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        startInfo.Verb = "runas"
        Dim myProcess As Process = Nothing
        Try
            myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
            Do
                If myProcess.HasExited Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Install complete")
                End If
            Loop While Not myProcess.WaitForExit(1000)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)
        End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Go the answer already.

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c msiexec /i " & path & "\IDGo800_Minidriver_64.msi"" ALLUSERS=1 /qn /norestart"""
```